# Mocking a method call on the same mock several times

Tags: mockito

While using Mockito

I am using the same mock across 2 test cases ( I know this is a bad test design, but this is an experiment)

```
@Test
public void test1()
{
    Mockito.when(mock.method1()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock temp) throws Throwable
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    ......
}

@Test
public void test2()
{
    Mockito.when(mock.method1()).thenReturn(false);
    ....
}
```

When the tests run in the order

test1

test2

the mocked method still returns true in test2. Is this expected behavior or is this a bug?

UPDATE:

1. The method is not final
2. I am using JUnit.

Comment: Is method1 final? If so, your real implementation is called in both cases.

Comment: Provide a complete, reproducible test case.

Comment: @user590849 Are you using JUnit or TestNG ?

Comment: I have answered all the comments as an update to the question.

Comment: It is expected behaviour. Who said that if you stub the same method twice the second call actually takes effect?

Comment: "who said' I did not understand. Nobody said but this seems like an intuitive behavior. I have a mock and I am setting its properties when I want. I can override its properties as well and it should just work. Just like you override the properties of an Object in OOP.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, Mockito recommends against reusing mocks in test cases.

That said, you might want to try resetting the mock in each test case:

```
   List mock = mock(List.class);
   when(mock.size()).thenReturn(10);
   mock.add(1);

   reset(mock);
   //at this point the mock forgot any interactions & stubbing
```

[Resetting mocks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17)

**If that doesn't help**

I also see you're using `thenAnswer()` in one method, and `thenReturn()` in the other.  Could you consider using `thenReturn()` in both cases?

Mockito includes this advice concerning callback stubbing in their documentation:

> We recommend using simple stubbing with thenReturn() or thenThrow() only.

[Stubbing with Callbacks](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#11)

Comment: Okay, but what is the need to reset the mock ? Also I cannot use thenReturn in both the cases, I need to use thenAnswer. But Mockito should work with both.

Comment: If you're reusing a mock across multiple test cases, then whatever changes are made to the mock in Test1 will also be present in Test2.  Resetting the mock in each test will do just that -- reset the mock to avoid this from occurring.